# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings after excluding logback

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

Issue is two versions of slf4j is getting added to class path (one from logback) because of which server is throwing an error.

Logback jar is getting added to classpath but its not visible anywhere in dependency hierarchy in eclipse . Is there any way to find from where it is coming.I am using maven and i am new to it so trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question, again?

Comment: @MWiesner : my question is i am getting this above error in bamboo server logs, i have exluded logback dependency from pom.xml also still the error is same.

Comment: From your last comment it seems you use maven, something you forgot to mention in the question ...

Comment: @Henry : Ya i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

to show which dependencies are being pulled in, and from where.